# List files in ftp active mode

Tags: python, ftp, scapy

I am trying to capture ftp packets using scapy. I need to capture the ftp file listing packet when I type the ftp command "ls".

I searched online and found that file listing should be done in passive mode, but that means server port will change; it will not be 21 which I use in scapy to recognize the ftp packets from other packets.

Is there a way I can list the files in active mode? Or another way to capture the listing package in scapy while the server port is a variable "not 21"?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I mean do I always have to type "pass" before I type "ls" when I am connected to the ftp server? Because otherwise it gives me this error: "500 Illegal Port Commands on FTP Prompt". In general, I want to capture the packet that contains the list of files when it sent from the server, using Scapy in Python. But I can't set the condition in python to detect this packet because its port no. is not 21 because the connection is in Passive mode.

Comment: I am the client, and I can use either active or passive mode connections. I need to capture the ftp listing packet sent from the server

Answer (score 0):

If you have a complete control over the FTP connection, you can use both passive and active mode to retrieve the directory listing.

Though with active mode, the server has to be able to connect to your machine, what is often not possible due to ubiquitous firewalls and NATs. Read *my* article on [network setup needed for FTP active and passive connection modes](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ftp_modes).

In active mode, the server should use outgoing port 20 for the directory listing. Though if firewall/NAT is involved, the real port, that your client (and Scapy) will see, can be completely different anyway. So it may not help in the end.

---

With passive mode, you would have to inspect the main (control) connection and detect what port will be used for the listing/data connection and start inspecting that port too. Scapy may even have that functionality (or part of it) built-in, I'm not familiar with Scapy.

Comment: scapy != scrapy

Comment: @Cukic0d Thanks. Corrected.